# How to Load paper.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I have recently started working with Paper.js

I did as mentioned in the tutorial but couldn't get any output. I have mentioned the code below. Can someone please help me to solve the problem ?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>

<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
var path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';

var start = new Point(100,200);
path.moveTo(start);
path.lineTo(start + [100,100]);

</head>

<body>


<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure where to put the different files inside my computer. Please help.

Comment: This code is from you html file. And you have defined src="js/paper.js", it is relative path. Means in folder where is your html file there should be folder "js" containing "paper.js".

Comment: @AndreasM. I tried that too. It just doesn't work. I have edited the code which I am currently using. Can you please look into it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the script end tag,

```
</script>
```

right before the

```
</head>
```

tag.

Answer (score -1):

Found it. It's embarrassing. Missed the  tag !